# Network monitoring tool on linux for home broadband router

Tags: linux, broadband, network-monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitor the bandwidth usage of each computer on a network](https://superuser.com/questions/82966/monitor-the-bandwidth-usage-of-each-computer-on-a-network)

I have broadband router at my home, and 3 systems are connected to it through Wifi. I want to monitor or measure how much bandwidth is being consumed by each system at a given time. I dont want cumulative usage, I just want to know at a given moment. So the software need not be running all the time. Is there a utility for linux which I can install on my system, and monitor the usage of all the three systems ( including mine ) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monitor the bandwidth usage of each computer on a network](http://superuser.com/questions/82966/monitor-the-bandwidth-usage-of-each-computer-on-a-network) and/or [How to monitor bandwidth use of each device on wifi network](http://superuser.com/questions/94499/how-to-monitor-bandwidth-use-of-each-device-on-wifi-network) and/or [How can I monitor internet usage in my network?](http://superuser.com/questions/54549/how-can-i-monitor-internet-usage-in-my-network)